# Uncaught mysqli_sql_exception: MySQL server has gone away

Tags: database, mariadb

I got reported by website visitors that they receive randomly a Error 500 message.
I checked the logfiles, which show the following:

> http.log
>
> [Mon Oct 09 08:36:18.605780 2023] [proxy_fcgi:error] [pid 31212:tid 140018349766208] [client 79.101.xx.xxx:0] AH01071: Got error 'PHP message: PHP Fatal error:
> Uncaught mysqli_sql_exception: MySQL server has gone away in /home/web/app.xx.com/public_html/backend/functions.php:2990\nStack trace:\n#0 /home/web/app.xx.com/public_html/backend/functions.php(2990): mysqli->query()\n#1 /home/web/app.xx.com/public_html/backend/functions.php(3294): get_disk_size_stat_uploaded()\n#2 /home/web/app.xx.com/public_html/backend/index.php(110): update_user_space_storage()\n#3 {main}\n  thrown in /home/web/app.xx.com/public_html/backend/functions.php on line 2990', referer: https://app.xx.com/backend/login

> mysql.log:
>
> 2023-10-09  5:48:06 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '127.0.0.1'.
> 2023-10-09  5:48:06 0 [Note] /usr/sbin/mariadbd: ready for connections.
> Version: '10.6.12-MariaDB-0ubuntu0.22.04.1'  socket: '/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'  port: 3306  Ubuntu 22.04
> 2023-10-09  5:48:06 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) load completed at 231009  5:48:06
> 2023-10-09  7:06:16 1140 [Warning] Aborted connection 1140 to db: 'app_db' user: 'app_user' host: 'localhost' (Got timeout reading communication packets)
> 2023-10-09  7:07:42 1155 [Warning] Aborted connection 1155 to db: 'app_db' user: 'app_user' host: 'localhost' (Got timeout reading communication packets)
> 2023-10-09  7:13:12 1202 [Warning] Aborted connection 1202 to db: 'app_db' user: 'app_user' host: 'localhost' (Got timeout reading communication packets)
> 2023-10-09  7:15:01 1217 [Warning] Aborted connection 1217 to db: 'app_db' user: 'app_user' host: 'localhost' (Got timeout reading communication packets)
> 2023-10-09  8:35:21 2311 [Warning] Aborted connection 2311 to db: 'app_db' user: 'app_user' host: 'localhost' (Got timeout reading communication packets)
> 2023-10-09  8:36:06 2317 [Warning] Aborted connection 2317 to db: 'app_db' user: 'app_user' host: 'localhost' (Got timeout reading communication packets)

To me it look if it has some memory or space issue. But I check the RAM and HDD. Ram is about 6.5 GB free space. And disk is 50% (about 20GB) free.

Comment: Raise the MariaDB server variable `max_allowed_packet` to account for the size of data returned by your query.